# what better? Use the Provider of asp.net or not use?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

what best practice?
If i will not use the provider I will need to make table of Session, roles, my tables and other....

if the provider better, how can I build custom register with connection to another tables(foreign keys)? how can i get the current user in registration(with sessionid?)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your requirements.

---

The following articles could be helpfull:

[Introduction to Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx)

[How To: Use Membership in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648345.aspx)

[MembershipProvider Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.aspx)

[[How Do I:] Create a Custom Membership Provider?](http://www.asp.net/general/videos/how-do-i-create-a-custom-membership-provider) (Video)

Answer (score 0):

Why reinvent he wheel? Best practice would be to use the provider model and if if you have any requirements out of the ordinary create your own custom membership provider (Akram has posted a link on how to do this).

If you are using windows forms there are a lot of examples out there of how to use the membership controls with the membership provider saving you a lot of time.